# can't expand (and keep expanded), the detail table for my radgrid. 

Tags: client-side, radgrid

I'm using a telerik radgrid.  I want to expand the item that is currently being edited to show detail. I have created a function to fire when the OnCommand event occurs.  What happens is the details expand, and then contract again!  It doesn't matter how I set the HierarchyLoadMode for the master or details, I've tried every setting I can think of and it still won't stay expanded when the master data item goes into edit mode.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Users.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebCallManagerData.Account.Users" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnCommand(sender, args)
        {

            if (args.get_commandName() == 'Edit')
            {
                rowIndex = args.get_commandArgument();
                var radGrid = $find("<%= rgUsers.ClientID %>");
                var dataItem = radGrid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[rowIndex];
                dataItem.set_expanded(true);

            }
            else if (args.get_commandName() == 'ExpandCollapse')
            {
                //dumpObject(args);
            }

        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ForeColor="Red" Text="" ID="DisplayMessage1" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rgUsers">
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgUsers" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" DataSourceID="odsUsers"
        GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnCommand="OnCommand" />
            <Selecting CellSelectionMode="None"></Selecting>
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView DataSourceID="odsUsers" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True"
            AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" DataKeyNames="UserName" HierarchyLoadMode="Client">
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView runat="server" DataSourceID="odsUserRole" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True" EditMode="EditForms" HierarchyLoadMode="Client">
                    <ParentTableRelation>
                        <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="UserName" MasterKeyField="UserName" />
                    </ParentTableRelation>
                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditFormSettings>
                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
                        </EditColumn>
                    </EditFormSettings>
                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>
            <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" FilterControlAltText="Filter UserName column"
                    HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" UniqueName="UserName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email" FilterControlAltText="Filter Email column"
                    HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" UniqueName="Email">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Approved" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter Approved column"
                    HeaderText="Approved" SortExpression="Approved" UniqueName="Approved">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="LockedOut" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter LockedOut column"
                    HeaderText="LockedOut" SortExpression="LockedOut" UniqueName="LockedOut">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Creation" FilterControlAltText="Filter Creation column"
                    HeaderText="Creation" SortExpression="Creation" UniqueName="Creation" DataType="System.DateTime">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastLogin" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter LastLogin column"
                    HeaderText="LastLogin" SortExpression="LastLogin" UniqueName="LastLogin">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastActivity" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter LastActivity column"
                    HeaderText="LastActivity" SortExpression="LastActivity" UniqueName="LastActivity">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastPasswordChanged" DataType="System.DateTime"
                    FilterControlAltText="Filter LastPasswordChanged column" HeaderText="LastPasswordChanged"
                    SortExpression="LastPasswordChanged" UniqueName="LastPasswordChanged">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Online" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter Online column"
                    HeaderText="Online" SortExpression="Online" UniqueName="Online">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Password" FilterControlAltText="Filter Password column"
                    HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" UniqueName="Password">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                </EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
        </FilterMenu>
        <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
        </HeaderContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsUserRole" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetUserRoles"
        TypeName="WebCallManagerData.Account.MemberShipHelper.User" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        UpdateMethod="UpdateUserRoles">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ur" Type="Object" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsUsers" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllUsers" TypeName="WebCallManagerData.Account.MemberShipHelper.User">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This could happen if you use an older version of RadGrid where this function is not available.
You have to have at least Q3 2011 version:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/whats-new/release-history/q3-2011-version-2011-3-1115.aspx

Comment: I upgraded to Q1 2012 today and still get the same error.  I updated the references in my project to the new DLL's.  It should be simple to expand a row if a user clicks on edit, I have tried 100 ways with no good results...

Comment: Can you expose a public url with a simple demo showing the problem?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not getting email notifications of responses for some reason.  I finally upgraded properly (another nightmare in itself with Telerik) and now I don't get the error.  I still cannot, however, expand my detail table under an item on the client side with out it subsequently collapsing.  Telerik's documentation is very very very very very frustrating to say the least.